# Open Gl rotating vectors around axis and roll

Tags: opengl-es

In `opengl Es2`, I am rotating the camera (forward, up, and sideways) per the code below.

However, this method is introducing roll into the view. If I comment out one or the other (heading or pitch) there is no roll.

`theading` and `tpitch` are usually only 1 or 2 degrees (or -1 or -2).

**Any ideas on eliminating roll?**

```
 //rotate heading
    this.rotate_XYZ(cam.right, tHeading, cam.up);
    this.rotate_XYZ(cam.forward, tHeading, cam.up);         
 //rotate pitch

    this.rotate_XYZ(cam.up, tPitch, cam.right);
    this.rotate_XYZ(cam.forward, tPitch, cam.right);    

public void rotate_XYZ(j3Vector sVector,float angle, j3Vector a){

Matrix.setIdentityM(this.mCameraRotateMatrix, 0);
Matrix.rotateM(this.mCameraRotateMatrix, 0, angle, a.x, a.y, a.z);

this.mRHS_Vector[0]=sVector.x;
this.mRHS_Vector[1]=sVector.y;
this.mRHS_Vector[2]=sVector.z;


Matrix.multiplyMV(this.mRESULT_Vector,0, mCameraRotateMatrix,0,this.mRHS_Vector, 0);

sVector.set(this.mRESULT_Vector[0],this.mRESULT_Vector[1],this.mRESULT_Vector[2]);

return; 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution

Rotate around world up and rotate cam up as well.

```
//rotate heading
this.rotate_XYZ(cam.right, tHeading, world.up);
this.rotate_XYZ(cam.forward, tHeading, world.up);         
this.rotate_XYZ(cam.up, tHeading, world.up);
```

//rotate pitch

```
this.rotate_XYZ(cam.up, tPitch, cam.right);
this.rotate_XYZ(cam.forward, tPitch, cam.right);    

public void rotate_XYZ(j3Vector sVector,float angle, j3Vector a){

 Matrix.setIdentityM(this.mCameraRotateMatrix, 0);
 Matrix.rotateM(this.mCameraRotateMatrix, 0, angle, a.x, a.y, a.z);

 this.mRHS_Vector[0]=sVector.x;
 this.mRHS_Vector[1]=sVector.y;
 this.mRHS_Vector[2]=sVector.z;


 Matrix.multiplyMV(this.mRESULT_Vector,0, mCameraRotateMatrix,0,this.mRHS_Vector, 0);

 sVector.set(this.mRESULT_Vector[0],this.mRESULT_Vector[1],this.mRESULT_Vector[2]);

 return; 


 }
```